# What does the time complexity n^(O(k)) signify?

Tags: time-complexity, np

I came across a problem recently and read that it could be decided in time n^(O(k)) and that this still implies that the problem is in NP. What does this complexity represent? How is it a non-deterministic polynomial time complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It implies that its in NP because P is a subset of NP, and n^(O(k)) is polynomial when k is constant.

So if it can be decided in a polynomial time then its in P, and P is in NP so the problem is also in NP.

EDIT:
This is under the assumption that k is a constant or "smaller" than n (when n->infinite)

Comment: Also, n^(O(k)) is more commonly written O(n^k), which makes the polynomial more obvious.

Comment: Thanks that does clear up quite a bit. Though I'm still not clear how a problem could yield that complexity(i.e. n^(O(k))). What does that complexity semantically mean?